# Debian 11 failed to resolve .local names

Tags: debian, mdns

**Update (6 Dec 2021):**
It seems like there is a bug somewhere in avahi or libnss_mdns, see https://github.com/lathiat/nss-mdns/issues/81
Bad timing.

I have 2 single board computers running Debian 11, none of which is able to resolve any host in .local domain using mDNS out of the box.
Here is the ping's output running on **junk.local**:

```
brain@junk:~$ ping atom.local    
ping: atom.local: Name or service not known
```

Pinging **atom.local** from my PC running Ubuntu, works okay:

```
brain@home:~$ ping atom.local
PING atom.local (192.168.0.135) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from atomic (192.168.0.135): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.394 ms
```

Both of them are accessible by their names, "atom.local" and "junk.local" using Ubuntu 21.10, Windows and iOS. The hardware are same, both machines get their network settings through DHCP service on my router. On the **atom.local** network is managed by networking (basic server installation), on the **junk.local** - by NetworkManager (desktop + KDE installation). I tried a lot of guides, configuring avahi, nsswitch, systemd-resolved, NetworkManager, non of which working for me. Tinkering with /etc/resolv.conf I was able to get some results

1. **nameserver 192.168.0.1** That is default DNS server (my router), .local hosts can't be resolved. Same result ifI use my ISP's DNS servers.
2. **nameserver 127.0.0.1** .local names are resolved, and nothing else for obvious reasons.
3. **nameserver 127.0.0.53** I copied it from my Ubuntu PC and everything works fine! Also, I get same result using Google's 8.8.8.8

Now I have a question: How do I properly configure this mDNS thing? Why it is working fine with Google DNS server? I'm a bit confused after reading a ton of howtos and answers on this site.

In my nsswitch.conf I have this line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

**avahi-resolve** and **avahi-browse** works fine on these machines.

If I use 127.0.0.53 or 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver, I get IPV6 address

```
brain@junk:~$ getent hosts atom.local
fe80::207:32ff:fe4e:7d17 atom.local
```

So this `mdns4_minimal` does nothing at all? Now I'm totally confused.

Comment: mDNS and DNS are two different protocols; also IPv4 and IPv6 are too different network stacks. The ideas seem to be a bit mixed up

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro Yes, I know. Very helpful, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

For minimal server install it is enough use combo **systemd-networkd** + **systemd-resolved**.

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`
Uncomment `MulticastDNS=yes`

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/10-lan.network`
I used simple configuration:

```
[Match]
Name=enp1s0 #Put your interface here

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
MulticastDNS=yes
```

Enable **networkd** and **resolved** services, start them up:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

Disable/mask default networking service:

```
sudo systemctl disable networking
```

Rename or remove old networking stuff, this step is crucial to keep **/etc/resolv.conf** controlled by **resolved** service:

```
sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.save
```

Finally it works, yay!